# 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am very new to android. I know this question is duplicate, i tried all solution from SO but i cloud not fix my problem.I hope you understand.Here is my code to retrieve data from `MYSQL` and displayed into `table` format. But I stuck with some where. I tried lot of solution to fix my problem but i failed to get output. Every time i run my app it goes on crushed.Also i failed in display data in table view.

main.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://IP/stat_api/myjson.json");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("log_tag", "Connection Success");
            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “pass”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in HTTP Connection" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int flag = 1;
            for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                if (flag == 1) {
                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tv1.setText("eid");
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tv1.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(tv1);

                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tv2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    tv2.setTextSize(15);
                    tv2.setText("name");
                    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tr.addView(tv2);

                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tv3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    tv3.setText("user_name");
                    tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tv3.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(tv3);

                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline = new View(MainActivity.this);
                    vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                    vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tv.addView(vline);
                    flag = 0;
                } else {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag", "eid: " + json_data.getInt("eid") + ", name: " + json_data.getString("name") + ", user_name: " + json_data.getString("user_name"));
                    TextView b = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    String stime = String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("eid"));
                    b.setText(stime);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    b.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b);

                    TextView b1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    b1.setTextSize(15);
                    String stime1 = json_data.getString("name");
                    b1.setText(stime1);
                    b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tr.addView(b1);
                    TextView b2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    String stime2 = json_data.getString("user_name");
                    b2.setText(stime2);
                    b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b2.setTextSize(15);
                    tr.addView(b2);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline1 = new View(MainActivity.this);
                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline1);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

myjson.json

```
    [{
    "eid": "1",
    "name": "karthi",
    "user_name": "admin",
    "password": "rootsquare",
    "privilege": "1",
    "dob": "2016-09-03",
    "address": "99, xyz bla bla, abc.",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "9876543210",
    "blood_gp": "B+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "2",
    "name": "raja",
    "user_name": "emp",
    "password": "emp",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "2016-09-07",
    "address": "100, abc, xyz, bla bla",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "9638527410",
    "blood_gp": "A+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "3",
    "name": "X",
    "user_name": "xxx",
    "password": "xxx",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "2016-09-07",
    "address": "cbe",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "9876543210",
    "blood_gp": "A+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "4",
    "name": "testuser",
    "user_name": "testpwd",
    "password": "255",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "2016-09-01",
    "address": "cbe",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "000000000",
    "blood_gp": "A+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "5",
    "name": "test",
    "user_name": "userr",
    "password": "testpwd",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "1991-09-03",
    "address": "cbe",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "000000000",
    "blood_gp": "A+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "6",
    "name": "karthi",
    "user_name": "karthi",
    "password": "karthi",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "1991-09-03",
    "address": "udt",
    "city": "tip",
    "mobile": "9500892145",
    "blood_gp": "B+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "7",
    "name": "raja",
    "user_name": "raja",
    "password": "raja",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "1990-03-02",
    "address": "cbe",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "99876543210",
    "blood_gp": "A+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "8",
    "name": "kk",
    "user_name": "kk",
    "password": "kk",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "1991-02-03",
    "address": "cbe",
    "city": "cbe",
    "mobile": "99876543210",
    "blood_gp": "b+",
    "status": "0"
}, {
    "eid": "9",
    "name": "zz",
    "user_name": "zz",
    "password": "zz",
    "privilege": "2",
    "dob": "2000-01-05",
    "address": "cc",
    "city": "cc",
    "mobile": "9874254482",
    "blood_gp": "o+",
    "status": "0"
}]
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.example.newtable.newtable, PID: 5668


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newtable.newtable/com.example.newtable.newtable.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                                 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                                 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
                                                                                 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
                                                                                 at com.example.newtable.newtable.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: please post your logcat.

Comment: yes bro i update it @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan Do you actually get the result in your JSONArray or not? Have you checked that by debuging

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan Please make sure you get the proper response from the server and your JSONArray have that result.

Comment: @GrIsHu , i unable to debugging because app cloud not enter. before then it will close

Comment: The reponse is the problem here, acually i dont know why response is empty. @GrIsHu

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan If you are not getting response from the server then check on the server side there can be any issue. Also check your logcat whether you get any error or not.

Comment: @GrIsHu  I run my server side code it return the result

Answer (score -1):

You're actually consuming api, not reading from database. Good solution is not to parse JSON manually, but use Gson library and POJO schema

Comment: Thanks for response first. can you please give some e.g.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html   https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Comment: okay thank you. why above code not working any idea ? or my code have wrong concept like that?

Comment: Some string is null (maybe json has no such a field). Click in error output and it will show you line with error.

Comment: By the way, parsing json is a quite long operation, you should not do it on a main thread.

Comment: yes i get error in this line `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`

Comment: Then 'result' is null - maybe, http request failed. It is worthy to use Retrofit + RxJava instead - you'll know if request is successful and get parsed objects in result.

Comment: Gson parses Json; but Retrofit makes REST calls and it uses Gson (and rxJava for concurrency)

Comment: This can be put in comments only.